# sphinxql is slower after upgrade

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, search-engine, sphinx

I have upgraded sphinx version from 2.1.9 to 2.2.9 .

I am facing an issue in the queries performance . the older version is faster than the new one about 200 % . is this a configuration issue  in the new version ?

**my case :**

on production environment I am using a distributed index on 13 machines , each machine has 3000000 documents . the document size is around 300kb .

I am simulating this production environment on a development one with a distributed index , 2 indexes and each has 4000000 documents , I have both versions on the same machine and I am trying some queries on both ... the newer version is slower !

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: @barryhunter I have updated the question with more details , please check it .. and do you need me to provide some queries and the config file ? Thanks

Comment: yes. provided detail doesn't really say much.

Comment: @barryhunter done , kindly check the update i added links to both config file and the queries i am testing . Thanks

Comment: removing config files since no answer ..